# Bind event to child element of directive in link function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I need to bind an event to directive's children which is prepared with ng-repeat in templateUrl. I am trying to bind the event in `link` function but the children are not yet prepared.

Here is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/jAVrx1f7X2XtDtTNQCm9?p=preview).

Here I want to bind `click` event on `li` tag which are prepared with ng-repeat.But by the time, the `link` is executed, the `li` elements are not yet prepared.

[image]

Comment: the worst approach is do it with timeout, but in your place, I would do it by applying directive in li not in parent

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've resolved the same problem with the angular $timeout

```js
link: function (scope, element) {
    $timeout(function () {
        element.on('click', '#Id', function () {
            console.log('inside event handler of the first child)
        })
    })
}
```

Try this by injecting $timeout in your directive

Comment: "Error: [jqLite:onargs] jqLite#on() does not support the `selector` or `eventData` parameters

Comment: Should note that this only works if you include jQuery.  Otherwise Angular uses jqLite which doesn't support the selector parameter.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution #1** 
using angular ng-click directive ([`plunker`](http://plnkr.co/edit/bOLnQxREdMZbXIlIH1Vf?p=preview))

```
<button ng-click="showValuePopup = !showValuePopup;">Click</button>
<div ng-show="showValuePopup">
    <ul>
        <li ng-click="$parent.showValuePopup = false;" ng-repeat="option in options" value="{{ option.value }}"
            symbol="{{ option.symbol }}">{{ option.text }}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Solution #2** 
use additional directive with timeout that fire event after ng-repeat last element loads ([`plunker`](http://plnkr.co/edit/s5jM1CzVDTVC70Hg2kTM))

```
app.directive('onLastRepeat', function () {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        if (scope.$last) setTimeout(function () {
            debugger;
            scope.$emit('onRepeatLast', element, attrs);
        }, 1);
    };
});
```

and listen for this event in link function:

```
$scope.$on('onRepeatLast', function(scope, element, attrs){
    // make what you want
    valuePopup.find('li').on('click',function(){
        valuePopup.hide();
    });
    valuePopup.find('keydown').on('click',function(){
        valuePopup.hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: Since,I couldn't find any other solution, I was tend to follow your solution.But I would like to wait for some more time for any alternative solution,so I m not going to mark it as accepted answer. I will mark it as accepted,if I won't find any other solution.

Answer (score 0):

maybe it will help you

```
app.directive('gtmsCycleButton', function () {
    return{
        restrict: 'EA',
        link: function (scope, el, attrs) {

            scope.$watch(attrs.options, function(newVal, oldVal) {

                if (newVal === oldVal) return;

                var btn = $(el).find('.v-btn'),
                    valuePopup = $(el).find('.v-value-popup');

                btn.on('click', function() {
                    console.log('Button Clicked');
                    valuePopup.toggle().focus();
                });

                valuePopup.find('li').on('click', function() {
                    valuePopup.hide();
                });

                valuePopup.find('keydown').on('click', function() {
                    valuePopup.hide();
                });
            });            
        },
        templateUrl: 'temp1'
    }
});
```