# AngularJS - How do I bind click functions to child elements

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'd like to bind click functions to these list items in this angular directive, but I have no idea how to do this... element links to the whole div, but how to create a click listener for all these list items... ?

```
    app.directive('paginaLijst', function() {
    return {
    templateUrl: 'js/templates/paginas.html',
    restrict: 'AE',
    replace: true,
    link: function( $scope, element, attrs) {

        element.bind('mouseenter', function () {
            element.css('background-color', 'yellow');
        });
        element.bind('mouseleave', function () {
            element.css('background-color', 'white');
        });
    }
};
});
```

and this the template

```
<div ng-class="colSizeList" class="beheer a-show-hide" id="opdrachten" ng-hide="opdActive">
 <h4>Beheer opdrachten</h4>
 <ul class="list-group">
<li class='list-group-item  opdracht' ng-class="{ 'active': $index == selectedIndex }" ng-repeat="opdracht in opdrachten">
        <a href="#">
                <span>{{opdracht.vak}}</span>
                <small>{{opdracht.titel}}</small>
        </a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't want to hover but on click... As i said in the main post.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27656721/bind-event-to-child-element-of-directive-in-link-function

Comment: Why do you want do to it inside the link function instead of using a simple ng-click ?

Comment: you can use ng-click on li itslef.

Comment: Well then element still refers to the head div..

Comment: Aren't you supposed to do it in a directive link function?

Answer (score 0):

change to this selector:

```
element.find('li').bind(...)
```

`.find()` jqLite method is limited to tagname lookup so, you have to put the target element tagname.

Comment: This is not angular way.

Comment: @Nitheesh have you heard of jqLite? [jqLite](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)